# Gulp watch fails to even start on huge number of files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a problem running gulp watch on huge number of files (>=40000). I have latest gulp (3.9.1), node (6.4.0), npm (3.10.3).

To replicate error you have to create sample files
`mkdir test && cd test && for i in {1..40000}; do echo "tt" >> test$i; done`

gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp')

var src = './**/*';
// works normally 
//var src = './*'; 

gulp.task('watch', function () {
   gulp.watch(src, {read: false}).on('change', function(file) {
    console.log('watch running');
   });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Running watch on directory with that many files just fails without any error. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: what about splitting your project into smaller chunks?

Comment: Can't do, splitting script for smaller parts doesn't work as well. Currently I found a workaround by using other tool (lsyncd) and my own script for what I've wanted to do.